# how to rotate image 90 digree on both direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am very tried from myself but solving my problem.
My query is:
I have a image I want to rotate this image  as flip from start to 90 degree in slow motion and come back from the same way for 90 degree.
please let me know the solution, how will I do?

Thanks in advanced.

i  used this code

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .img {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -khtml-transform:speed 5s;
  -khtml-transform:speed 5s; /* Safari */
  }
  </style>



   <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
   $(window).load(function(){

  /*$('#image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('img');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('img');
  });*/

  //setTimeout(addclass(),5000)
  setTimeout(function(){ addclass(); },5000);

  });//]]>  
  function addclass(){
    $("#add_remove").hide();


  $("#image").addClass('img');
  setTimeout(function(){ removeclass(); },5000);

  }

   function removeclass(){
    $("#add_remove").show();

   $("#image").removeClass('img');
   setTimeout(function(){ addclass(); },5000);

  }

  </script>


  </head>
  <body>
     <img id="image" src="robot_upper.png"/>

   </body>
```

Comment: Why don't you google `image processing` or `image rotation`? Or show us the code which you've tried to write and failed?

Comment: Look for CSS3 transforms and transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 Transition and Animation
Here is the link and go study.
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for clockwise and anti-clockwise

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

and

```
 transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

Comment: Tnanks for repply  but i wannt  horizately  flip in slow motion

Comment: Use {transform: rotateY(180deg);transition: 0.6s;}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after but this does do the rotating.

Edit:

Thought I would post the code here to see if it helps at all.

I have set up the elements as you did and then just used CSS animations to control the transition.

CSS:

```
/* defines the animation to be used, in this case I have called it 'waving', please note the browser pre-fixes are required for this to work cross browser */
@-webkit-keyframes waving {
  0%  {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes waving {
  0%  {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes waving {
  0%  {
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes waving {
  0%  {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

#image {
  -webkit-animation: waving 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    waving 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      waving 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         waving 5s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/alexbaulch/pen/uFnki)

Comment: Thnanks   for reply  but i want make horizatal flip in slow motion .

Comment: I have updated the code to do horizontal flipping, let me know if that works for you